# Creating a folder in the "AppData\Roaming" directory [Python]

Tags: python, windows, sqlite, appdata

Is there actually a way of doing this? I've tried using the following code:

`file_path = os.environ['APPDATA'] + "\\Example\\example.db"`
`sqlite3.connect(file_path)`

But it comes up with an error. My only thought would be that it's permissions-related, but if that was the case, then I probably wouldn't create a file there, either... I'm stumped. Anyone got any idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try like this,

```
import os
dir_path = '%s\\Example\\' %  os.environ['APPDATA'] 
if not os.path.exists(dir_path):
    os.makedirs(dir_path)

file_path = '%sexample.db' % dir_path
sqlite3.connect(file_path)
```

Comment: And for those used to using [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join): `dir_path = os.path.join(os.environ['APPDATA'], 'Example')`.